# how to get value from winform textbox and add to database field

Tags: c#

i have two table(kala,reception) and two winforms(kala,reception), i want when i fill the reception form(specialy txtqty) and insert the data, it(txtqty) adds to kala table field(txtkqty). how can i write this code behind the button in reception form.
reception form:

```
private void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string check = br.createreceipt(int.Parse(txtreceptcode.Text),
                                            int.Parse(comboBox_kala.SelectedValue.ToString()),
                                            int.Parse(comboBox_suplier.SelectedValue.ToString()
                                                ), int.Parse(txtqty.Text), DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker_recept.Text));
            if (check == "true")
            {
                dtrecept = br.getdata();
                dataGridViewrecept.DataSource = dtrecept;
                txtreceptcode.Text = null;
                txtqty.Text = null;
            }


        }
```

kala form

```
 private void btnkalainsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string check = bk.createkala(int.Parse(txtkalacode.Text), txtkalaname.Text, int.Parse(txtkqty.Text),
                                         int.Parse(txtkalapoint.Text));
            if (check=="true")
            {
                dt = bk.Getdata();
                dataGridViewkala.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(check);
            }
        }
```

reception DAL:

```
namespace DAL
{
  public  class TblreceiptionDal
    {
        SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=store;Integrated Security=true");
        public DataTable getall()
        {
            DataSet ds=new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter("Spinforeceip", cn);
            sa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sa.Fill(ds, "Spinforeceip");
            return ds.Tables["Spinforeceip"];
        }
        public string createreceipt(int recept_id,int kala_id,int suplier_id,int recept_qty ,DateTime recept_date)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sptblreception_insert", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_id", recept_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_id", kala_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suplier_id", suplier_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_qty", recept_qty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_date", recept_date);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "true";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
                throw;
            }

        }
        public String deletereceipt(int recept_id)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sptblreception_delete",cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_id", recept_id);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "true";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
        public string updatereceipt(int recept_id,int kala_id,int suplier_id,int recept_qty ,DateTime recept_date)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sptblreception_update", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_id", recept_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_id", kala_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suplier_id", suplier_id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_qty", recept_qty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_date", recept_date);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "true";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
      public string receptgetbyid(int recept_id)
      {
          try
          {
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sptblreception_getbyid",cn);
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recept_id", recept_id);
              cn.Open();
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              cn.Close();
              return "true";

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              return ex.Message;
              throw;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

reception BLL:

```
namespace BLL
{
   public class Bllreceipt
    {
         TblreceiptionDal tr = new TblreceiptionDal();
       public DataTable getdata()
       {
           return tr.getall();
       }
       public string createreceipt(int recept_id,int kala_id,int suplier_id,int recept_qty ,DateTime recept_date)
       {
           return tr.createreceipt(recept_id, kala_id, suplier_id, recept_qty, recept_date);
       }
       public String deletereceipt(int recept_id)
       {
           return tr.deletereceipt(recept_id);
       }
       public string updatereceipt(int recept_id,int kala_id,int suplier_id,int recept_qty ,DateTime recept_date)
       {
           return tr.updatereceipt(recept_id, kala_id, suplier_id, recept_qty, recept_date);
       }
        public string receptgetbyid(int recept_id)
        {
            return tr.receptgetbyid(recept_id);
        }
    }
}
```

kala DAL:

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class TblkalaDal
    {
        SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=store;Integrated Security=True");
        public DataTable Getdata()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds=new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Sptblkala_getdata",cn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(ds, "Sptblkala_getdata");
                return ds.Tables["Sptblkala_getdata"];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
                throw;
            }
        }
public string createkala(int kala_id,string kala_name,int kala_qty,int kala_orderpoint)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sptblkala_insert", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_id", kala_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_name", kala_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_qty", kala_qty);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_orderpoint", kala_orderpoint);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        return "true";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
        throw;
    }

}
        public string Deletekala(int kala_id)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand dm = new SqlCommand("Sptblkala_delete", cn);
                dm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_id", kala_id);
                cn.Open();
                dm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "true";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             return   ex.Message;
                throw;
            }

        }

        public string updatekala(int kala_id,string kala_name,int kala_qty,int kala_orderpoint)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand uk = new SqlCommand("Sptblkala_update", cn);
                uk.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                uk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_id", kala_id);
                uk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_name", kala_name);
                uk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_qty", kala_qty);
                uk.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kala_orderpoint", kala_orderpoint);
                cn.Open();
                uk.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "true";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kala BLL:

```
namespace BLL
{
    public class bllkala
    {
        TblkalaDal tk=new TblkalaDal();
        public string createkala(int kala_id,string kala_name,int kala_qty,int kala_orderpoint)
        {
            return tk.createkala(kala_id, kala_name, kala_qty, kala_orderpoint);
        }
        public string deletekala(int kala_id)
        {
            return tk.Deletekala(kala_id);
        }
        public string updatekala(int kala_id,string kala_name,int kala_qty,int kala_orderpoint)
        {
            return tk.updatekala(kala_id, kala_name, kala_qty, kala_orderpoint);
        }
        public DataTable Getdata()
        {
          return  tk.Getdata();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi. Check my answer, if you feel I haven't got your point tell me to correct my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution :

```
Form frm = Application.OpenForms["formName"];  
TextBox txt = (TextBox)frm.Controls.Find("textboxName",true)[0];  
txt.Text = "yourValue";
```

Just be careful, this code is not safe, do the safety parts yourself (try catch can be good approach, you can also do it by checking error prone parts in if/else blocks)

Comment: @Sami, did you try my code? this code should solve your problem, you first get the destination form (receipt) then you find the textbox on it (txtqty) then you assign the value (whatever it is) to the textbox. That's it. Any questions yet? I'm available.

Comment: your code didnot work for me. i want when i press the btninsert in reception form, at first my reception table in database be filled.(i know this code, i did). second the value of text box quantity(txtqty) of reception form be added to my quantity of kala table in database.

Comment: you mean you want the database code? or a code that simply copies the txtqty value of reception form to the text of txtqty in form kala?

Comment: do you want a global variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17974/discussion-between-mahdi-tahsildari-and-sami)